# C algorithm for Partition issues

Tags: c, algorithm, data-partitioning

Given a set of integers S:

How can the set be divided into k parts such that the sum of each part is minimal?
Please give also a `C` implementation.

Example:

```
S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} and k = 3
```

The partition

```
 S1 = {1, 6}
 S2 = {2, 5}
 S3 = {3, 4}
```

has the property that the sum of each partition is minimal.

Comment: Looks like Homework to me... :D

Comment: Nope, just curious to know your ideas or algorithms to compute this as fast as posiible, could be just pseudocode instead of  `C` code

Comment: What if some parts have different sums. Are we trying to minimize the maximum sum of the partitions?

Comment: No, we're trying to divide the numbers as "fair as possible" so that biggest difference between two partition sums is as small as possible. Read the introduction on the page I linked, it's very good at explaining the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page describes the problem fairly well and even provides pseudocode for an algorithm:

http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK2/NODE45.HTM

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, the algorithm you suggest solves it assuming the arrangement is kept the same.

Answer (score 1):

Determine min, max in the given list and form a pair. 
Repeat until the list is exhausted.

Intuitively it seems it will ensure the desired result, but not sure though!

Comment: I guess the same thing.